# Gson how to get serialized name

Tags: java, gson

When we define a class with following format

```
public class Field {
    @SerializedName("name")
    public String name;
    @SerializedName("category")
    public String category;

}
```

for the `JsonObject` content

```
{
    "name" : "string",
    "category" : "string",
}
```

and using `Gson` to parse the content

```
Field field = new GsonBuilder().create().fromJson(
                content, Field.class);
```

So,my question is can we use `Gson` to get the `@Serialized` name. For in this instance I want to know what `@Serialized` name is used for `field.name`,which is `name` and for `field.category` which is `category`.

As per suggested by @Sotirios Delimanolis, using `Reflection` we can get the `Serialized` name

```
java.lang.reflect.Field fields = Field.class.getDeclaredField("name");             
SerializedName sName =fields.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);            
System.out.println(sName.value());
```

Comment: if we have `"name"` then there is no need of using reflection and getting the value. is there a way to get only from field like just using the variable `name` without actually using the String "name"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use reflection to retrieve the `Field` object you want. You can then use [`Field#getAnnotation(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29)  to get a `SerializedName` instance on which you can call `value()` to get the name.

Comment: I am using like this `field` is my `Object` of class `Field`. And I am using `field.name.getClass().getAnnotation(SerializedName.class).value()`. But it gives me `NullPointer Exception`.

Comment: @laaptu It doesn't help that your class is named `Field`. I meant `java.lang.reflect.Field`. Get the `Class` object of **your** `Field` class and use `getDeclaredField()` to get the `Field` object for your `name` field.

Comment: `java.lang.reflect.Field fields = Field.class.getDeclaredField("name");
   SerializedName sName =fields.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);
   System.out.println(sName.value());` Thanks for it. But isn't there any other method that I can implement without `reflection` as I heard that `reflection` is CPU intensive. And I am developing this for `Android `

Comment: @laaptu No, reflection is the only way to do what you are asking for. What do you really need this for anyway?

Comment: @Solitrious Delimanolis: What I want is that I want to make `POST` request to the server,using the values that I parsed using `Gson`library. Meaning ,I want to send the `POST` params as   `{"name":"userInputValue","category":"userInputCategory"}`i.e. using the same `@Serialized("name")` name value to use as `POST` key.

Comment: @laaptu You can try deserializing the json into a Map or JsonObject and iterating over the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing with `Field.class`, can't you parse it into a `JsonObject.class` instead? Then use `JsonObject.get()`:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(content, JsonObject.class);
String serializedName = jsonObject.get("name").getAsString();
```

Note that [`.getAsString()`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html#getAsString--) will return it as a String without embedded double quotes, compare this to when you call `toString()`.

---

One thing I was trying to do was serialize an enum field, which is not an object. In that case, you can serialize using `JsonElement.class`, since it's just a primitive:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
JsonElement jsonElement = gson.fromJson("\"a\"", JsonElement.class);
String serializedName = jsonElement.getAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thats a way with `alternate` for example for a more complex example

### Enum class

```
public enum SomeStatusCd {

    @SerializedName(
        value = "status_1",
        alternate = {"an alternate 1", "an alternate 2"}
    )
    STATUS_1("status_1")
    ....
}
```

### get the enum from alternate

```
public static SomeStatusCd getFromAlternate(String alternateFieldName){
    SomeStatusCd result = null;
    Field[] statusDeclaredFields = SomeStatusCd.class.getDeclaredFields();
    String foundEnumName = null;
    for (Field statusDeclaredField : statusDeclaredFields) {
        SerializedName annotation = statusDeclaredField.getAnnotation(SerializedName.class);
        if (annotation != null){
            String[] declaredFieldAlternates = annotation.alternate();
            for (String declaredFieldAlternate : declaredFieldAlternates) {
                if (declaredFieldAlternate.equals(alternateFieldName)){
                    foundEnumName = statusDeclaredField.getName();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (foundEnumName != null){
        for (SomeStatusCd enumConstant : SomeStatusCd.class.getEnumConstants()) {
            if (enumConstant.name().equals(foundEnumName)){
                result = enumConstant;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

### Test it

```
    SomeStatusCd fromAlternate = getFromAlternate("an alternate 1");
    assertSame(fromAlternate, SomeStatusCd.STATUS_1);
```